# How to use MigLayout in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, miglayout

I have no idea how to get MigLayout to work in IntelliJ (I'm sort of a noob at IntelliJ). I am currently using the 2017.3.5 community edition.

I've downloaded the jar file, but I can't seem to import it correctly.

I have `import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;` at the top of my main file, but
when I try to compile my code, I keep getting an error

`Error:(40, 30) java: cannot access net.miginfocom.layout.LC
  class file for net.miginfocom.layout.LC not found`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added it to the class path?

Comment: Which jar file exactly did you download?

Comment: The filename is `miglayout-swing-5.1-20180128.230035-1029`. I can't remember exactly where I got it, but I believe I got it from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/miglayout/miglayout-swing/5.1-SNAPSHOT/), which I found via [miglayout.com](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Also include the core lib. You can get it [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/miglayout/miglayout-core/5.1-SNAPSHOT/)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late. But it will help somebody.
IntelliJ Idea will allow to download a maven dependency as a Jar file under the lib folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:
File->Project Structure->select Modules on the left-> choose the Dependencies tab-> find the + either at ther right or bottom-> add the .jar